# My Jenkins jobs and some configurations disappeared after restart

Tags: jenkins

I am using old version Jenkins 2., Just i restarted the jenkins through GUI mode, after restart I can't see any jobs, when I log into jenkins server, I can see jobs and other stuff.

What I need to do to get all that stuff to get back.

Please help me

Again I restarted the server, I can't see any jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Log onto the server that you are hosting Jenkins on and go to the $JENKINS_HOME. This is the directory where everything related to your installation of Jenkins is held, including all the jobs. Inside the Jenkins home folder, there should be a folder called "jobs". This "jobs" folder contains all the configurations you used in your jobs (as well as any information related the previous builds your ran). There should be a folder for each job that is named with the name of each job, which contains a "config.xml", which holds the jobs configurations.

Check each of these parts one by one. If any part is missing your job wouldn't show. In the best case, all these configurations are still available in your machine and Jenkins is looking in the wrong place for the configurations, meaning you can just point Jenkins to the correct location and everything will start to show. Worst case the actual configurations are all gone.